# Proving concurrence of lines relating tangent line

Tags: geometry

Given triangle $ABC$ inscribed circle $(O)$. $D$, $E$ are on sides $AC$, $AB$, respectively. $BD$ meets $(O)$ at $M$ and $CE$ meets $(O)$ at $N$. Line $DE$ meets $(O)$ at $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $MN$, $PQ$ and the tangent line at $A$ are concurrent.
[image]

I have tried using Pappus or Pascal theorem with "$AA$" in the 6 points but give out no results. I've also tried using harmonic division to quadrilateral $MNPQ$, but it didn't work. Please help me with the strategies, thanks!